# Using If condtion in Visual Force page

Tags: visualforce, formula-field, conditional

I am trying to display fields on the basis is value is null or not. I have used below code. Its not working. I am still wondering where is mistake.

I checked and confirms c.FlagEncrypted__c has values and not null.

```
 <apex:column headerValue="SSsk" rendered="{!IF(c.FlagEncrypted__c!=null,'YES','NO')} ">
  <apex:inputField value="{!c.FlagEncrypted__c}"/>
 </apex:column>
```

Answer (score 1):

Boolean values are always "true" or "false". Further, you never need an IF statement when doing a comparison. The following version should work equally well:

```
rendered="{!c.FlagEncrypted__c!=null}"
```

If you insist on using IF, then you *must* use TRUE or FALSE, and should not be in quotes:

```
rendered="{!IF(c.FlagEncrypted__c!=null,TRUE,FALSE)}"
```

Finally, it's considered idiomatic to use formula-style evaluation, so ideally you should write:

```
rendered="{!NOT(ISBLANK(c.FlagEncrypted__c))}"
```

Comment: Thanks SFDCFOX. Its not working for me, i found on page its displaying inputfield, but my coloum name is not comming. All rows are shifting one coloum head. Please advise. Should i put rendered condition in <apex:inputField value="{!c.FlagEncrypted__c}"/> also.

Comment: @DavidMycka No, rendered should affect the entire column. There's probably something else wrong in your code.

Comment: @DavidMycka You can't use the field on a record for the header, because technically you haven't "entered the loop" yet. That's probably why it's behaving oddly.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcbox. This column is part of pageblockTable where i am populating  othere fields easily like c.firstname, c.lastname. Those are comming right. Please suggest.